# SCCM 2012 R2 and SQL, which SQL license to use

Tags: sql-server, sccm

I've got SCCM 2012 R2 installed at a client with SQL Server 2012 SP1 installed in evaluation mode (as the client could not find their install key). I've heard that SQL Server licensing is included with System Center these days, but when the client (a smaller education institution) accesses their licensing, they see a large list of SQL Server versions listed, but every version says 'This version of the product does not require a key'.

Now I'm concerned, because leaving the installation in Evaluation mode will mean that SQL Server will fold up shop and not open after 180 days. Is there some special mechanism that bypasses licensing for SQL Server when ConfigMgr is installed? Why do I not see any valid license keys for SQL Server on the clients Software Assurance / Education licensing page?

Did I use the wrong version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, for anyone else stuck in the same problem.

If you use the ISO that you download from your volume license page, the SQL Server ISO should include the 'free SCCM' license baked in.

However, if you try to run this installer side-by-side on a server with a pre-existing install, SQL Server Setup will detect the other instance of SQL and not actually display the key.  It will instead revert to displaying the 'Choose Evaluation or enter key screen'.

I found a way around though, wrote it up here: [SCCM's SQL Stuck in Eval mode? How to fix!](http://foxdeploy.com/2015/02/12/is-your-sccm-sql-stuck-in-evaluation-mode-dont-despair/)

In summary: download the SQL Server ISO found in the Volume License Center under System Center 2012 Configuration Manager, and run the installer on a clean server.  This time you'll be able to see the pre-filled key, copy it and use this as your upgrade key using SQL Edition Upgrade from the SQL Setup.  You'll get a warning stating 'Unsupported Upgrade Path' since the evaluation mode defaults to Enterprise, and the 'free' key is for Standard only, but it will still work.